# Difference between zip() functions in Python 2 and Python 3

Tags: python, zip

I was wondering what the difference is between the `zip()` function in python 2 and python 3 is. I noticed when using the `timeit` module on both functions that the python 3 function was a lot faster. Thanks so much in advance :)

Comment: One thing is that in *Python3*, it returns a *generator*.

Comment: Python 2's `zip` builds and returns a list. Python 3's `zip` returns a lazy iterator. If you actually iterate over both of them, Python 3's will save memory but have the same effect. But if you never try to use the values, Python 3 will be even smarter and just never generate them, which is of course amazingly fast, but not that useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difference between Python 2 and Python 3 is Python 3 returns an iterators. Idea of this saving memory.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, the `zip()` function returns an iterator, meaning that you can only exhaust elements once, whereas Python 2 returns an iterable itself.

see here:
[Python 2 Doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip), [Python 3 Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)